# Django 1.5 custom user model plus admin.autodiscover() breaks app

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I have a custom user model (it's actually named `User` as I didn't see any need to name it otherwise) in my Django 1.5c1 project (currently running on the latest from the Django 1.5 branch on github).  `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is defined in my settings properly, so the `auth` module works correctly and I can log in etc. fine.

However, with the custom user module enabled, the admin site doesn't work.  When I add `admin.autodiscover()` to my `urls.py`, every page on the site (not just admin pages) throws a `NotRegistered` exception and says `The model User is not registered`.  The traceback shows that `admin.autodiscover()` is trying to call `admin.site.unregister(User)`, apparently before it has registered that model.

I tried renaming my user model to something other than `User`, but it didn't seem to work.  I also tried creating my own `admin.py` for that app, and then I tried manually registering my custom `User` model with the custom `UserAdmin` model specified in `admin.py` before `admin.autodiscover()` ran, but that actually caused a separate exception saying that `User` was already registered.

What should I try next in order to get `admin.autodiscover()` working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a brand new empty project with a custom user model and attempted to recreate the situation, which led to a diagnosis: we had added the `django-usertools` package to the project, which has not been updated for Django 1.5 and apparently conflicts with custom user models.  Removing that package from the installed apps list in settings resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to jump through a few extra hoops if you want your custom User model to work with the admin.  From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin):

> ...your User model must define some additional attributes and methods.
>   These methods allow the admin to control access of the User to admin
>   content:
>
> `class models.CustomUser`
>
> > `is_staff` True if the user is allowed to have access to the admin site.
> >
> > `is_active` True if the user account is currently active.
> >
> > `has_perm(perm, obj=None)` True if the user has the named
> >     permission.
> >
> > `has_module_perms(app_label)` True if the user has perm
> >     to access models in the given app.